# How can one install and launch PostgreSQL and Python by clicking the Python-based executable file?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, windows, pyinstaller, customtkinter

"I have developed a Python application that installs and launches both Python and the PostgreSQL database. Now, I aim to package it as a standalone application. While I have successfully packaged everything into a single executable using PyInstaller, I encounter a failure upon launch, specifically when attempting to establish a connection to the database if it doesn't already exist. The Python code works flawlessly on Linux OS, but I am facing issues on Windows since the PostgreSQL installation commands used on Linux are not compatible."

```
self.commands = [
{'cmd': 'sudo apt-get install python3.10 -y', 'flag': False,'value': 'sudo'},
{'cmd':'sudo apt-get install postgresql -y','flag':False, 'value': 'sql'},
{'cmd':'sudo -u postgres createuser --createdb --username postgres --no-createrole --no-superuser --encrypted odoo17','flag':False,'value':'user_pass'},]

command executing code :

elif value =='sql':
                cmd = cmd.split()
                cmd.insert(1, "-S")
                cmd = " ".join(cmd)
                # Provide sudo password as input
                cmd_password = admin_password + "\n"
                process = subprocess.run(cmd.split(), capture_output=True, text=True, input=cmd_password)
elif value == 'sudo':
                cmd = cmd.split()
                cmd.insert(1, "-S")
                cmd = " ".join(cmd)
                cmd_password = admin_password + "\n"
                process = subprocess.run(cmd.split(), capture_output=True, text=True, input=cmd_password)
```

This task is accomplished using Tkinter; however, the identical code does not function on Windows. I lack the knowledge of how to generate an executable file on the Windows platform.

My goal is to streamline the installation process into a single step that creates, configures, and launches the database if it is not already present, in addition to installing the application's executable. I am particularly focused on creating installers for the Windows platform.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.